# About Custom Device Actions

Tags: python, google-assistant-sdk

I follow the instruction (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/custom-actions) to set a "blinklight" Custom Device Actions,
but it's not working.

I went to "deviceregistration" page, but i can't see the "blinklight" traits. in
the list.

I ran the example code, and get the log below:

```
"device_model_id: pegagooleassistnatcplusplus-pegagoogleassistantcplusplus-v5mnh8
device_id: 075C580BE09EBB9D304FEBA605EEFA59

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {"is_muted": false}
ON_MEDIA_STATE_IDLE
ON_START_FINISHED

ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {"text": "blinking 5 times"}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {"is_error_response": false}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {"with_follow_on_turn": false}
```

Comment: You're saying "blinking' instead of "blink"?

Comment: I re-registered a new Device Model, and
Trying to deploy blinking example action, then I tried
"blink 5 times" "blinking 5 times" currently available
The response is perla hub did't support on this device
which part did i do wrong ?

Comment: Thank your response. 
Did i need to deploy custom action to production state or i can use it in alpha state ?

Comment: You should be able to set it up as "test", ie. `gactions test ...`

Comment: blinking example works, thank your help.